# Angular2 [typescript] error while injection Http to service

Tags: angular, angular2-services

Sources with problem: https://github.com/clicman/angular2-app/

I`ve tried to inject Http to service and it leads with error:

```
http:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <__exec @ system.src.js:1374entry.execute @
 system.src.js:3300linkDynamicModule @ system.src.js:2921link @ system.src.js:2764execute @
 system.src.js:3096doDynamicExecute @ system.src.js:715link @ system.src.js:908doLink @
 system.src.js:569updateLinkSetOnLoad @ system.src.js:617(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:430run @
 angular2-polyfills.js:138zoneBoundFn @ angular2-polyfills.js:111lib$es6$promise$$internal$$tryCatch @
 angular2-polyfills.js:1511lib$es6$promise$$internal$$invokeCallback @
 angular2-polyfills.js:1523lib$es6$promise$$internal$$publish @ angular2-polyfills.js:1494(anonymous
 function) @ angular2-polyfills.js:243run @ angular2-polyfills.js:138zoneBoundFn @
 angular2-polyfills.js:111lib$es6$promise$asap$$flush @ angular2-polyfills.js:1305 
angular2-polyfills.js:138 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
    Evaluating http://localhost:3000/angular2/src/http/http
    Error loading http://localhost:3000/scripts/boot.js
```

Service code:

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core'
import {Http} from 'angular2/src/http/http';
@Injectable()
export class CommentsService {
  constructor(private _http: Http) { }
  public getComments(): any[] {
    return [];
  }
}
```

What I do wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should add the `angular2/bundles/http.dev.js` to the `index.html`

Comment: Great! It works now. Thank you. Is some tools to automate needed scripts to index.html?

Comment: No, not really. When you start using 'routing' you have to add the routing module from angular. But all the components you write are automatically loaded by systemjs

Comment: Just a note to others. `http.dev.js` needs to be added AFTER `system.src.js`